# how to convert folder of pickle files into single csv file

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I have a directory containing about 1700 pickle file, that every file is all Twitter post of the user, I want to convert it into a folder of CSV files, that every CSV file name is the name of the pickle file and each row contains one tweet of user...
after that, I want just the top 20 CSV with more samples than others... how can I do that?

```
# khabarlist = open_file_linebyline(pkl_path)
def open_dir_in_dict(input_path):
    files = os.scandir(input_path)
    my_dict = {}
    for file in files:
        # if len(file.name.split()) > 1:
        #     continue
        # if file.split('.')[-1] != "pkl":

        with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
            items = [i.strip() for i in f.read().split(",")]
        my_dict[file.replace(".pkl", "")] = items
        df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
        df.to_excel(file.replace(".pkl", "") + "xlsx")


open_dir_in_dict("Raw/")
```

I Wrote the sample code for it and it did not work...

Comment: I found an answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
def open_dir_in_dict(input_path):
    files = os.scandir(input_path)
    my_dict = {}
    for file in files:
        if len(file.name.split()) > 1:
            continue
        if file.split('.')[-1] != "pkl":

            with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='replace') as f:
                print(f.readlines())
                items = [i.strip() for i in f.read().split(",")]  # encode('utf-8').strip()
        my_dict[file.replace(".pkl", "")] = items
        df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
        df.to_excel(file.replace(".pkl", "") + "xlsx")


# open_dir_in_dict("Raw/")
```

Answer (score 0):

and a better answer...

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import regex as re

data_path = "/content/drive/My Drive/twint/Data/pkl/Data/"
for path in os.listdir(data_path):
    my_tweets = []
    df = pd.read_pickle(data_path + path)
    for tweet in df.tweet:
        url = re.findall(r"http\S+", tweet)
        if url == []:
            my_tweets.append(tweet)
    new_df = pd.DataFrame({"tweets": my_tweets, "author": path.replace(".pkl", "")})  # path[:-4]
    new_df.to_csv("/content/drive/My Drive/twint/final.csv", index=False, mode="a", )
```